# Unable to change status of file in Git

Tags: git

There is some files in repo that **Git** can't commit/restore/reset/e.t.c.

[image]

All of that started from "deleted" status for a file, that I didn't move into repo and which actualy was **not** deleted.

[image]

`git rm` actualy deleted the file and `git restore --staged` does **nothing**

[image]

[image]

Another behaviour step-by-step:

1. `git commit -m com` does **nothing**

[image]

2. **Removing** the files via **Windows Explorer** makes `git status` look that way

[image]

3. Then `git add . && git commit -m com2` makes files to go to **commit actually**

[image]

I am using:

- Windows 10 LTSC 1809
- git 2.27.0.windows.1
- JetBrains Rider 2019.3.2
- Unity 2019.4.1f1

**Update:**
Removing `.git/index` and performing `git reset` fixes the problem. Maybe file was corupted because of anti-malware services
[image]

Comment: have you tried "git reset <filename>"?

Comment: @codegorilla checked one more time - same as `git reset`

Comment: Juste poking blindly : is the filesystem mounted on `D:\Projects\cognitive-reality` a regular NTFS partition ? is it a shared directory ?

Comment: @LeGEC NTFS, Primary, no shared access

Comment: Have you tried ```git reset <filepath/file name>``` instead of just plain reset? I don’t see that on first glance. I may be missing iy

Comment: @yes-siz answered above - I tried, same result

Comment: It's not at all clear what's happening, but the symptoms match up with Git being unable to update the index file (`.git/index`). Is some process holding it read-only, e.g., some anti-malware program?